# Visual Studio Intellisense is not working with Boost

Tags: visual-studio-2008, boost, intellisense

I'm using Visual studio 2008.

Recently, I installed Boost library to use geometry algorithm. When I typed some keywords related boost library, the intellisense function didn't work. I want to see related method and variable in a structure or a class, but i can't.

In normal class or structure, the intellisense is good working.

How can I use intellisense function with boost library in visual studio?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when in Project Properties, 'Additional Include Directories' I had set it to be a relative path like "\Libraries\Boost" (relative to the drive).

Then I change the relative path to absolute one "C:\Libraries\Boost". This fixed the intellisense.

Answer (score -1):

I use boost and I get intellisense completion ok.

Most of boost is in the include files, so make sure you are setting up the project properties to point to the boost include directories (Property Pages/C++/Additional Include Directories)

and that the file you are working on is including the correct boost include file.
for example

`#include <boost/thread/mutex.hpp>`